# different range of values in a column to be treated as different buckets and create pie chart R

Tags: r, pie-chart

In a dataframe, I have a column which has values(price) from 1 to 500. I need to create a pie chart with 3 buckets, 1-10, 10-50, greater than 100. 
It should show the percentage contribution to it. 
How to do this in R?

Comment: These are two different questions: "Cut numeric vector into bins"; "Plot pie-chart" and there are multiple questions like that on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does that help you:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- as_tibble(seq(1,500)) %>% rename(price=value)
```

so the data looks like (its stupid, but its an example, use your data):

```
# A tibble: 500 x 1
    price
    <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
7     7
8     8
9     9
10    10
# ... with 490 more rows
```

than we do:

```
df %>%
  mutate(bucket=ifelse(price<=10, "1-10", 
                       ifelse(price>10 & price<=50, "11-50", "50<"))) %>% 
  count(bucket) %>%
  mutate(percent=n/nrow(df)*100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=percent, fill=bucket)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)
```

with `mutate` we define the buckets and the percentage. with `ifelse` we simply say: `if` price = x, `than` mark it as y, `else` do ...

That's the resulting chart:

[image]